# How can I change permalinks to use a different domain and path from where the blog is hosted?

Tags: permalinks, proxy

Here's my situation:

I'm hosting my blog at blog.foo.com.

I have a completely different app on foo.com.

I want my blog url to be foo.com/blog.

I've set up a reverse proxy on foo.com so that foo.com/blog/123 is fetched from blog.foo.com/123. This is working.

The problem is that all the links generated in the blog still use blog.foo.com. I want them to instead use foo.com/blog. Is there a plugin that will do this?

(or: should I be using a different approach entirely?)

Comment: I could be wrong, but change your WordPress Address and Site Address to match the URL. I'm not 100% sure if it's going to work the way it's setup, but you can always try...

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: What happened once you changed the settings? Is WordPress installed on the same directory (blog.foo.com or blog.foo.com/wordpress)?

Comment: Is it installed in the same directory as what?

Comment: okay moving the wordpress installation into a directory named /blog seems to have worked, thanks!