# How can I change all links on pages to point to a different domain from where the site is hosted?

Tags: urls, site-url

I saw this question: [How can I change permalinks to use a different domain and path from where the blog is hosted?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258516/how-can-i-change-permalinks-to-use-a-different-domain-and-path-from-where-the-bl) and was wondering if someone can help me.

We're hosting a wordpress blog on WP Engine (e.g. blog.wpengine.com)
We have a different app hosted on Azure (e.g. at site.com.au) and are using a reverse proxy to serve the content (hosted on blog.wpengine.com) in a sub-folder of site.com.au This is working fine.

The problem is that all the links generated in the blog still point to the base URL of blog.wpengine.com. I want them to point to site.com.au.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this when a wordpress blog is hosted separately and when using a reverse proxy?

Comment: Any luck on this ? I'm in the same position developing and would love to know how you got around it.